# SQL - Grouping by Last Day of Quarter

Tags: sql, date, join

I currently have a query running to average survey scores for agents. We use the date range of the LastDayOfTheQuarter and 180 days back to calculate these scores. I ran into an issue for this current quarter.

One of my agents hasn't received any surveys in 2020 which is causing the query to not pull the current lastdayofquarter and 180 days back of results.

The code I am using:

```
SELECT
Agent,
U.Position,
U.BranchDescription,
(ADDDATE(LastDayOfQuarter, -180)) AS MinDate, 
(LastDayOfQuarter) AS MaxDate,
COUNT(DISTINCT Response ID) as SurveyCount,
AVG(CASE WHEN Question ID = Q1_2 THEN Answer Value END) AS EngagedScore, 
AVG(CASE WHEN Question ID = Q1_3 THEN Answer Value END) AS KnowledgableScore, 
AVG(CASE WHEN Question ID = Q1_6 THEN Answer Value END) AS ValuedScore
FROM qualtrics_responses
LEFT JOIN date D
ON (D.`Date`) = (DATE(`End Date`))
LEFT JOIN `users` U 
ON U.`UserID` = `Agent ID`
WHERE `Agent` IS NOT NULL 
AND DATE(`End Date`) <= (`LastDayOfQuarter`) 
AND DATE(`End Date`) >= (ADDDATE(`LastDayOfQuarter`, -180))
GROUP BY  `Agent`,  (ADDDATE(`LastDayOfQuarter`, -180))
```

i know the issue is due to the way I am joining the dates and since he doesn't have a result in this current year, the end date to date join isn't grabbing the desired date range. I can't seem to come up with any alternatives. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms???  It's useless if someone give you solution to the wrong dbms.

Comment: Learn to use `GROUP BY ` properly.  Why are `U.Position`, `U.BranchDescription`, `LastDayOfQuarter` not in `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Eric: this smells like MySQL/MariaDB

Comment: What does the `date` table looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make the assumption that table `date` in your query is a calendar table, that stores the starts and ends of the quarters (most likely with one row per date in the quarter).

If so, you can solve this problem by rearranging the `join`s: first `cross join` the users and the calendar table to generate all possible combinations, then bring in the surveys table with a `left join`:

```
SELECT
    U.UserID,
    U.Position,
    U.BranchDescription,
    D.LastDayOfQuarter - interval 180 day AS MinDate, 
    D.LastDayOfQuarter AS MaxDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Q.ResponseID) as SurveyCount,
    AVG(CASE WHEN Q.QuestionID = 'Q1_2' THEN Q.Answer Value END) AS EngagedScore, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN Q.QuestionID = 'Q1_3' THEN Q.Answer Value END) AS KnowledgableScore, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN Q.QuestionID = 'Q1_6' THEN Q.Answer Value END) AS ValuedScore
FROM date D 
CROSS JOIN users U 
LEFT JOIN qualtrics_responses Q 
    ON  Q.EndDate >= D.Date
    AND Q.EndDate < D.Date + interval 1 day
    AND U.UserID = Q.AgentID
    AND Q.Agent IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    U.UserID,
    U.Position,
    U.BranchDescription,
    D.LastDayOfQuarter
```

Notes:

- I adapted the date arithmetics - this assumes that you are using MySQL, as the syntax of the query suggests
- You should really *qualify* all the columns in the query, by prefixing them with the alias of the table they belong to; this makes the query so much easier to understand. I gave a tried at it, you might need to review that.
- *All* non-aggregated columns should appear in the `group by` clause (also see the comment from Eric); this is a a requirement in most databaseses, and good practice anywhere